# How to change a labels text based on a successful ping?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, ping

So i have this program that needs to be connected to a certain server in our network, but in this case I will use 8.8.8.8. To make it easy to see if the connection is up I have a label that should say "yes" if connected and "no" if not. However I can't get it to work, this is the code I am using:

Sorry that wasn't descriptive enough indeed. It doesn't appear to do anything... Like the label doens't change at all. I've tried it on 2 different machine on Visual Studio 2017 and 2015. I can't wrap my head around it.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 4000;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    PingReply pingStatus = ping.Send(IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8"));

    if (pingStatus.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        label6.Text = "yes";
        label6.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    }

    else
    {
        label6.Text = "no";
        label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Edit: changed != to ==

Comment: "However I can't get it to work" isn't a very descriptive explanation of the problem. Have you debugged?

Comment: [Works fine](https://imgur.com/a/2HhwB). Is Form2_Load(...) linked up and being called?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't descriptive enough indeed. It doesn't appear to do anything... Like the label doens't change at all. I've tried it on 2 different machine on Visual Studio 2017 and 2015. I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on `timer1.Interval = 4000;` and `Ping ping = new Ping();`. Do either of them get hit? Do both of them get hit? As you can see from my screenshots, your code works _fine_.

Comment: And to reiterate my previous question (since this is the only thing I can see being the problem): Is `Form2`'s `Load` event actually linked to `Form2_Load`? Simply having a method called Form2_Load will not automatically link it.

Comment: Dear lord do I feel stupid. I didn't link the Form2_Load the correct way. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You will want to try something like the following;

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1.Interval = 4000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Start();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Address = "8.8.8.8";
        PingHost(Address);
    }
    public  bool PingHost(string Address)
    {
        bool Canping = false;
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        try
        {
            PingReply reply = ping.Send(Address);              
            label6.Text = reply.Status.ToString();
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        catch (PingException e)
        {
            label6.Text = e.ToString();
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        return Canping;
    }
```

This way by using `NetworkInformation` you can handle the returns a bit better.

However, having this check every 4 seconds might not be the best approach as this might have a knock on effect on performance but I guess this would all depend on what the application is needed for and the network you are pinging.

**EDIT**

The OP code does work but this maybe a more efficient way to handle this.

Comment: Flagged as "Not an answer" All you have done is moved the pinging code into a method from timer1_Tick. That doen't resolve OP's problem at all.

Comment: To those reviewing my flag: The OP has already confirmed in comments that he didn't link up the Form2_Load method to the form's load event, and other than that OP's code works fine. Tom's answer is a code review, not an answer and not even altertnative solution as all he has done is encapsulated the ping functionality in a method.